# My functions displays garbage, and some other times it displays clean result

Tags: c++, function, char, uppercase

I have to count the number of upper case and lower case letters in a given line. For this assignment, I have to use arrays of characters terminated by \0, which is what I do. I use ascii code to identify lower case or upper case letters.   However, the output is sometimes clean, sometimes not clean. Any help will be appreciated.  Here is my code in Dev-C++. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstring>


using namespace std;

int getline();
int isupper(char line[]);
int islower(char line[]);


int main()
{
  int  Month, last_digit;      //initialize variables and char array
  char temp[255]; 
  getline();

  getch();
  return 0;
}

int getline()
{
  char line[255];
  cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
  cin.getline (line, 255); 
  isupper(line);
  islower(line);
  getch();
  return 0;
}

int isupper(char line[])
{ 
  int y, i=0, k=0; int count_uppercase=0; char Uppercase_array[80];

  cout<<endl<<"from isupper function"<<endl;
  do
   { 
     y=line[i++]; // Convert to int
     if(y>64 && y<91)        //if it is a Uppercase letter...
     {
       Uppercase_array[k]=line[i-1];
       k++;          
       count_uppercase++;     //increment the counter...
     }
  }
  while(y);
  cout<<"Uppercase letter  = " <<Uppercase_array; 
  cout<<"   number of uppercase = "<<count_uppercase<<endl;
  cout<<"----------"<<endl;

  return 0; 

}

int islower(char line[])
{ 
  int z, i=0,  count_lowercase=0;
  cout<<"from lowercase function"<<endl;  
  do
  { 
    z=line[i++]; // Convert to int
    if(z>96 && z<123)     //if it is a Lowercase letter...
     count_lowercase++;      ////increment the counter...
  }
  while(z);
  cout<<"number of lowercase = "<<count_lowercase<<endl;    

  getch();
  return 0;
}

 *******example1 of output*****
 Enter a sentence: Good morning Dad, how ARE u?

from isupper function
Uppercase found in that line = GDARE√"   number of uppercase = 5
----------
from lowercase function
number of lowercase = 16

************example2 of output*********
Enter a sentence: Good morning Dad how are u?

from isupper function
Uppercase letter  = GD   number of uppercase = 2
----------
from lowercase function
number of lowercase = 19
```

Comment: First thing that jumps out at me is that your Uppercase_array is not null terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "garbage" you are referring to is the `√"` in `GDARE√"`, then the answer is to add the null-terminator `\0` to the last char of `Uppercase_array`. That is, after the do/while loop, add `Uppercase_array[k] = '\0'`.

Comment: Clear! very clear to me now. I will keep it in mind for now on. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at this line:

```
cout<<"Uppercase letter  = " <<Uppercase_array;
```

How does it know how many characters to output? You really should use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`.

If you want the simplest fix, do this before you print: `Uppercase_array[k]=0;`. C-style strings have their ends marked with a terminating nul (zero byte) which tells functions that handle them how big they are.

Comment: Great, it works fine now! can you explain a little bit more why Uppercase_array[k]=0 has fixed the problem? I really want to understand why this ligne itself solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: It might be clearer if you write `\0` rather than just 0.  It's the null character that marks the end of the string.  (It happens to have the ASCII value zero, which is why you *can* just write 0.)

Comment: clear now! I tend to forget the '\0' which terminates the string. Than you so much!